# How to plot a non-time based histogram in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

For instance, I record the duration for an event and would like to view a graph with the Y axis as count and the X axis as duration (which is recorded as an integer) so I can see the distribution of how long it takes the event to occur. How can I do this? Kibana seems to expect the X axis to be a time-based value, and won't except plain numbers. Is there a way to get around this I'm missing? Is there some logic behind this limitation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this as a terms panel with a bar or pie chart.  Just make sure you set the count high enough to cover how many values you have.

To bucket them into ranges, you'd need a [histogram aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) or [range aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) which Kibana isn't cable of doing as of 3.1

Comment: I tried the terms panel - it _almost_ works except that it removes any fields that are 0 (any idea how to fix that? even via code?). Thank you for the explanation on why the feature isn't yet in Kibana - I await Kibana 4 eagerly!

Answer (score 2):

Since Kibana 4, there is now an option for non-time based histograms.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I found it difficult to figure out on Kibana 7.x so here's a 2023 answer!

You can create a non-time based histogram via 2 different methods:

1. Lens UI (newer)

   - Visualizations > Create visualization > Lens
   - Change index pattern as necessary (top of right-hand side bar)
   - Under 'Horizontal axis' click Add and choose '**Intervals**' (not obvious at first!)
   - Then choose the field of interest (e.g. `event.duration`) and click 'Close' (bottom right)
   - Under 'Vertical axis' click Add and choose 'Count' leaving field as 'Records'
   - A histogram should appear (similar-ish to the screenshot of the classic UI below)
2. Classic UI:

   - Visualizations > Create visualization > Aggregation based > Vertical Bar (or Area)
   - Choose the relevant data source (e.g. an index pattern with HTTP access logs)
   - In the side panel under 'Metrics' leave Y-axis as 'Count'
   - In the side panel under 'Buckets' click Add > X-axis
   - Choose 'Histogram' from the Aggregation dropdown and the field of interest (e.g. `event.duration`)
   - Click 'Update' bottom right to get a histogram (e.g. in this case the distribution of request durations in nanoseconds)
     [image]